# How insert automatic ManyToMany with OpenJPA

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, openjpa

I have 2 classes mapped with OpenJPA.  One class is `User` and has relationship ManyToMany with the AppProfile.  In the database I have the table relations `USER_APP_PROFILES`  (ID,User_ID,App_ID).

My class Open JPA  User

```
@Table(name = "USER_PROFILE",schema = "BPMS")
public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Integer userID;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listUserProfile", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<AppProfile> listAppProfile;
}
```

My class AppProfile

```
@Table(name = "APP_PROFILE",schema = "BPMS")
public class AppProfile {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="APP_ID")
    private Integer appID;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name="USER_APP_PROFILES",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="APP_ID", referencedColumnName="APP_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="USER_ID")})
        private List<UserProfile> listUserProfile;
     }
```

I fetch a user into the database by EntitiyManager, after I add the List AppProfile.

Example:

```
UserProfile userProfile //(populate with fetch in database) 
AppProfile app = new App(); 
app.setAppID(11); 
List<AppProfile> listApp = new ArrayList<AppProfile>(); 
listApp.add(app);
userProfile.setListAppProfile(listApp); 
em.merge(userProfile)
```

How do I merge, if I need JPA automatic insert in table USER_APP_PROFILES:

```
User_App_Profile_ID  :  new register
UserID : 1  
AppID : 11
```

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Cascading

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `@JoinTable` to `UserProfile` (changing the parameters accordingly) and adding `cascade={CascadeType.ALL}` to the `@ManyToMany` annotation.

That should do the trick.